# SqlAdapter.Fill(DataSet) fills only first datatable returned by stored procedure in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, sqldataadapter

I try to fill my dataset with multiple tables using stored procedure on SQLServer. Code is simple:

```
var execProcedureString = "EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure ..."
var myDataSet = new DataSet();
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(execProcedureString, conn))
    {
         using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
         {
             adapter.Fill(myDataSet);
         }
    }
}
```

But somehow Fill only creates (and fills) first table (not the others). It is not about procedure because it returns normal data. Am I missing something in the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why Fill is not working. It worked before. There's walkaround (without need to specificate your datatables) but it envolves SqlDataReader

```
var execProcedureString = "EXEC dbo.SomeProcedure ..."
var myDataSet = new DataSet();

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(execProcedureString, conn))
    {
         conn.Open();
         using (var reader = new command.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while(!reader.IsClosed) //table.Load closes reader if it contains no more rows
             {
                 var table = new DataTable();
                 myDataset.Tables.Add(table);
                 table.Load(reader)
             }
         }
    }
}
```